# Video Editing Software - MKV?

Tags: video, video-editing

I want to edit MKV video files (anime). Naturally I want to use iMovie / Final Cut. But sadly they can't import MKV?

What is the recommended thing to do? Should I convert the files first or use a different software that does support MKV?

I'm a total newbie to video editing so I have no real attachment to any software, thanks!

Comment: I think you'll need to split the file into different parts - MKV is just a container format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend to convert it to a format that iMove can import. MKV is just a container format so  you probably already have an iMovie-compatible inside that package. Under Snow Leopard just install [Perian](http://perian.org/) and open it in QuickTime X and then go to File->Save as ... and choose a suitable format from the dropdown menu.

If you need more control over your conversion, you could also convert it to an iMovie-compatible format using any of the video conversion tools available for the Mac. For a long time VisualHub was the king of video format conversion, unfortunately [techspansion](http://www.techspansion.com/) the company behind it, closed its virtual doors. There are two main open-source options derived from VisualHub, [ReduxZero](http://transcoderredux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/transcoderredux/) and [TranscoderRedux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/transcoderredux/) they both should do the trick. Another option is [Subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/) which will also convert to and from MKV video containers to an iMovie-compatible format.

Comment: Thanks the Perian method works ok. How do I convert multiple files in batch? And since changing the container is so simple why can't final cut do it :S

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the container with ffmpeg:

```
for f in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy "${f%mkv}mov";done
```

ffmpeg can also be used to for example save a segment as a new file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -ss 0:37:55 -t 0:0:5 37.55-to-38.00.mkv
```

You can use mkvtoolnix to add or remove subtitles:

```
mkvmerge -i input.mkv # --identify
mkvmerge -o output.mkv input.mkv -S # remove all subtitle tracks
mkvmerge -o output.mkv input.mkv -s 3,4 # remove subtitle tracks 3 and 4
mkvmerge -o output.mkv input.mkv subs.srt # add subtitle track
mkvextract tracks input.mkv 3:subs.srt # save track 3 as subs.srt
```